# Spring+multiple gwt servlets

Tags: spring, gwt

1.From searching the web i understand that to use spring with gwt i would have to replace the default DispatcherServlet with org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet . But all the geomajas ( which uses spring + gwt ) examples i have seen use  in fact the supposed-to-be-replaced DispatcherServlet. How could i do that too? .

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <display-name>Geomajas application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            <!-- framework context -->
            classpath:org/geomajas/spring/geomajasContext.xml

            <!-- use rasterizing -->
            classpath:org/geomajas/plugin/rasterizing/DefaultRasterizedPipelines.xml

            <!-- application context -->
            WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            WEB-INF/layerOsm.xml
            WEB-INF/mapOsm.xml
       </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.geomajas.servlet.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- only needed for direct GWT -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.geomajas.servlet.PrepareScanningContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/geomajasWebContext.xml</param-value>
            <description>Spring Web-MVC specific (additional) context files.</description>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/d/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/${artifactId}/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

1. What modifications must i make  to the above file so that i can add another spring managed servlet ?

Comment: can someone make the 1. at the bottom a 2. ? I tried editing without success. In the editbox the number appears as 2. yet after i confirm the edits  the 1. remains

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I integrated Spring with GWT via |SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet`:

In`web.xml`:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/dispatch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nameOfYourApp/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Than, whenever you wish to define a Spring managed service, use `springGwtServices` in the `RemoteServiceRelativePath`:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/userService")
public interface UserService  extends RemoteService{

}
```

For an implementation example:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements UserService{

}
```

I hope this is what you needed

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This is interesting but i specifically want to do it using just the default dispatcher servlet. I have seen it is possible but i just can't tell how

Comment: Indeed, we are using the default dispatcher, and just adding the `SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet` to "translate" RPC calls: "It allows for transparent, automatic access to Spring beans as top level services from GWT Client code without extra servlets or the boilerplate RPC wrappers that are frequently needed for effective Spring/GWT integration" (From the project description)